# Сменить иконку при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: android

У меня есть приложение, с иконкой. В этом приложении есть кнопка "Сменить иконку". Так вот, мне нужно чтобы по нажатию на эту кнопку у activity менялась иконка в меню приложений. Возможно ли? Если да, то помогите кодом. Заранее спасибо

Comment: [Программирование — это то, в чём надо разбираться самому, либо не заниматься им вовсе.](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Замена иконки приложения из разряда хаков системы, сам я такого не делал, поэтому смотрите варианты [в этом ответе](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1103027), пробуйте. Потом отпишитесь, что получилось.

Comment: Да, спасибо) всё работает)

Comment: Если вы нашли решение самостоятельно, опубликуйте его в качестве ответа (кнопка "ответить на собственный вопрос"). Это поможет другим пользователям решить аналогичную проблемы быстрее.

Answer (score 0):

присваиваете кнопке слушатель событий, в слушателе изменяете иконку.

Comment: Вопрос только как изменять?

Answer (score 0):

```
        image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.otherImage);
        }
    });
```

Comment: нужно сменить иконку приложения